# installing cpuminer on Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64

Tags: 14.04, cpu

I have just set up a server and trying to install cpuminer following this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/cpuminer

I have downloaded **cpuminer** which is currently located at `/cpuminer`.

However, I'm not quite sure how to run the compile command.

I run the following:

```
cd cpuminer ./autogen.sh ./configure CFLAGS="-O3" make
```

This just returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default build directory is /home/[name]/tmp/, or other folder in  /home/[name]/. (Not the Desktop/).

No issues with Ubuntu 14.04.5 - 64 :

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config automake yasm git
```

---

```
$ cd tmp/
$ git clone https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer.git
$ cd cpuminer/
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

... and the executable `minerd` is created. And you can do : `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks, the reason was some of the dependencies didn't download, i went through and re-added them. Thanks!